# Writing Filename with Space in HDFS using Java URI.create causing it to fail with IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to execute the following snippet to save the file in HDFS.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
String targetFileStr = "/someDirectory/fileWith Space.txt"
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(targetFileStr), conf);
Path path = new Path(targetFileStr);
```

But it's failing with:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 26
at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:852)
```

I want to retain the space in filename.

Comment: Can you try encoding the filename ?

Comment: @NileshPS I tried encoding it using java.net.URLEncoder and space is replaced by + sign. But my concern is while saving the file into HDFS will it save with + or with space.

Answer (score 0):

There's an illegal character at index `26`, i.e. it doesn't like the space in the path. You can percent encode special characters like spaces. Replace it with a `%20` in this case.

```
String targetFileStr = "/someDirectory/fileWith Space.txt"
targetFileStr = targetFileStr.replaceAll(" ","%20");
```

You can also use [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html):

```
String targetFileStr = "/someDirectory/fileWith Space.txt"
targetFileStr = URLEncoder.encode(targetFileStr, "UTF-8");
```